# Can you do countif in aws quicksight with partial text?

Tags: amazon-web-services, countif, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to make a calculated field in AWS Quicksight for leads that have closed. However there are multiple closed statuses in use. I am trying to use

```
distinct_countif
```

and was wondering if there was a way to group all closed statuses into one - ex.

```
distinct_countif(id, status like '%Closed%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `locate` and `toLower` functions to solve this. The calculated field should more or less look like:

```
distinct_countif({id}, locate(toLower({status}), 'closed') <> 0)
```

Let me know if it works!

Documentation:

1. Locate: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/locate-function.html
2. toLower: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/toLower-function.html